# VHDL Configuration Across Block Statements

Tags: vhdl

Consider the following code:

```
entity foo is
end entity foo;

architecture a of foo is
begin
  assert false report "Architecture a";
end architecture a;

architecture b of foo is
begin
  assert false report "Architecture b";
end architecture b;

entity bar is
end entity bar;

architecture behav of bar is
  component foo is
  end component foo;
begin
  test_block : block
  begin
    foo_inst : foo;
  end block;
end architecture behav;
```

How do I specify a configuration for `foo_inst` to select between architecture a or b?  I've tried:

```
configuration test_cfg of bar is
  for behav
    for foo_inst : foo
      use entity work.foo(b);
    end for;
  end for;
end configuration test_cfg;
```

But this clearly doesn't work, as it doesn't get through the hierarchy:

```
** Error: j.vhd(28): Component instance "foo_inst : foo" not found.
** Note: j.vhd(32): VHDL Compiler exiting
```

How do I specify the `test_block` boundary in the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*clearly doesn't work*  [isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Show your analysis error message. Beside providing a line number identifying the cause the error message also reveals the tool you're using and the reason:

```
ghdl -a test_cfg.vhdl
test_cfg.vhdl:29:5:error: no component instantation with label "foo_inst"`. 
ghdl:error: compilation error
```

Where the problem is when analyzing the sixth design unit (the configuration declaration if you put all the VHDL in one design file) `foo_inst` isn't visible in bar(behav).

First some background from IEEE Std 1076-2008 -

3. Design entities and configurations
   3.1 General (para 2):

> A design entity may be described in terms of a hierarchy of *blocks*, each of which represents a portion of the whole design. The top-level block in such a hierarchy is the design entity itself; such a block is an *external* block that resides in a library and may be used as a component of other designs. Nested blocks in the hierarchy are *internal* blocks, defined by block statements (see 11.2).

The configuration declaration doesn't represent the design hierarchy here. There is no visibility into the block statement.

3.4.2 Block configuration

> A block configuration defines the configuration of a block. Such a block is either an internal block defined by a block statement or an external block defined by a design entity. If the block is an internal block, the defining block statement is either an explicit block statement or an implicit block statement that is itself defined by a generate statement.
>
> block_configuration ::=
>           **for** block_specification
>               { use_clause }
>               { configuration_item }
>       **end for** ;
>
> block_specification ::=
>         *architecture*_name
>       | *block_statement*_label
>       | *generate_statement*_label [ ( generate_specification ) ]
>
> ...
>
> configuration_item ::=
>         block_configuration
>       | component_configuration
>
> The block specification identifies the internal or external block to which this block configuration applies.
>
> ...

We see that a configuration item may be a block configuration, allowing hierarchical configuration specifications in the configuration declaration.

Where the configuration declaration can be modified to take advantage of this to specify which architecture to use for `foo_inst` in the block statement:

```vhdl
configuration test_cfg of bar is
    for behav
        for test_block
            for foo_inst: foo
                use entity work.foo(b);
            end for;
        end for;
    end for;
end configuration test_cfg;
```

We see that `test_block` is visible in bar(behav) and `foo_inst` is visible in `test_block`.

11. Concurrent statements
    11.1 General para 5:

> All concurrent statements may be labeled. Such labels are implicitly declared at the beginning of the declarative part of the innermost enclosing entity declaration, architecture body, block statement, or generate statement.

You label component instantiations and the block statement here so the labels are known and useable in a configuration specification found in the configuration declaration.

The rules for visibility in configuration declarations and specifications are found in 12.3 Visibility.